# AngularJS $scope undefined for item inside $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm quite new to AngularJS.

I've given myself a small project to create a list of local businesses and then the ability to 'like' each one - with the number of likes increasing by 1 each time the 'likes' div is clicked.

Here's my HTML

```
<ion-content ng-controller="BusCtrl" ng-init="init()" class="has-header">
<div class="list">
  <div ng-repeat="item in nodes" class="item">
    <b>{{item.node.title}}</b><br>
    <b>{{item.node.website}}</b><br>
    <img ng-src="{{ item.node.main_image.src }}">
    <div class="engagement">
      <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOne($index)">{{item.node.likes}}</p>
    </div>
    <span ng-bind-html="item.node.summary"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my controller code

```
.controller('BusCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    $http.get("sample-json/business-directory.json")
      .success(function(data) {
          $scope.nodes = data.nodes;
          $scope.plusOne = function(index) {
            $scope.nodes.node[index].likes += 1;
          };
          $scope.browse = function(v) {
            window.open(v, "_system", "location=yes");
          };
          window.localStorage["nodes"] = JSON.stringify(data.nodes);
      })
      .error(function(data) {
          console.log("ERROR: " + data);
          if(window.localStorage["nodes"] !== undefined) {
            $scope.entries = JSON.parse(window.localStorage["nodes"]);
          }
      });
  };
})
```

Here's some sample JSON

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "node": {
            "title": "2013 Business Survey",
            "website": "http://www.portumnachamber.ie",
            "likes": 0,
            "main_image": {
                "src": "http://portumnachamber.com/sites/default/files/styles/main-business-image-teaser/public/LOVEPORTUMNA_FINAL%20LOGO_%20small_3.jpg?itok=L5IE2Du_",
                "alt": "Portumna Business Survey 2013, What does Portumna Co. Galway need and want"
            }

        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "title": "All Occasions Boutique, Portumna",
            "website": "http://www.portumnachamber.com",
            "likes": 0,
            "main_image": {
                "src": "http://portumnachamber.com/sites/default/files/styles/main-business-image-teaser/public/all%20occasions%201.jpg?itok=LFvCQIAT",
                "alt": "Boutique Clothes Shop Portumna county Galway Ireland, All Occasions, Portumna"
            }

        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
            "title": "Anthony Williams",
            "website": "http://www.portumnachamber.com",
            "likes": 0,
            "main_image": {
                "src": "http://portumnachamber.com/sites/default/files/styles/main-business-image-teaser/public/default_images/portumna-coc-logo.png?itok=V9G81lx4",
                "alt": ""
            }

        }
    },
]
```

}

I get a list of each business - title, website, image, and the number 0 for likes. However, when I click on the 0, I get this error:

```
Error: $scope.nodes.node is undefined
```

It seems that it's a $scope within a $scope or something like that.

Any tips? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you show us `sample-json/business-directory.json` ?

Comment: HI Valepu - I've added some sample JSON to the question now.

Comment: Yes, because `$scope.nodes.node` does not exist. It should be `$scope.nodes[0].node` depending which number in the array you want to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that your nodes data source doesn't have another `node` array property on it. In this case, your function `plusOne` becomes:

```
$scope.plusOne = function(index) {
    $scope.nodes[index].node.likes += 1;
};
```

You are iterating ( `ng-repeat` ) on the `nodes` variable from your scope, so you have to put your `indexer` on that property. `$scope.nodes` is your array, not `$scope.nodes.node`. For each item from `$scope.nodes` you have a `node` property.

For example `$scope.nodes[0]` gives you first item which has a `.node` property.

Comment: Perfect. That words. Thanks a lot. Thanks also for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong structure.
Nodes is the array so you need to apply the index there, not to node. Node is an object which contains the parameter "likes".
The undefined item here was `nodes.node[index]` not the `$scope`

To access a node you should write `$scope.nodes[index].node.likes += 1;`

Comment: Perfect. That words. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are welcome. Please remember to accept one of the correct answers

Answer (score 0):

According to your JSON please change

```
$scope.nodes.node[index].likes += 1;
```

to

```
$scope.nodes[index].node.likes += 1;
```